# Given that $f(1)=1$, $f'(1)=-1,$ calculate $\int_0^t f(\alpha) \,\mathrm{d}\alpha$.

Tags: calculus

Given that $f(1)=1$, $f'(1)=-1,$ I'm trying to calculate calculate $\int_0^t f(\alpha) \,\mathrm{d}\alpha$.

My thoughts:
By FTC, 
$$
\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\int_0^t f(\alpha) \, \mathrm d \alpha=f(t)=1,
$$
 but this doesn't seem to use the extra information. What should I do?

Comment: I'm not convinced that there is a unique solution to this..

Comment: Other conditions are required (e.g. a ODE...). Otherwise the integral can be anything.

Comment: The FTC isn't applied correctly unless you assume $f' = f$ and $f(0) = 0$ wich then implies that $f(t)\not\equiv 1$ as claimed after use of FTC...

Comment: All we can say is $$\int_0^t f(\alpha) \mathrm{d}\alpha\in\mathbb C$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at $f_1(t) = 2-t$ and $f_2(t) = e^{1-t}$. What do you notice?